# "DRM_IOCTL_MODE_GETRESOURCES" not equal to "0xA0" as defined in drm.h

Tags: c++, linux, g++, drm

I'm trying to use ioctl() in C++ under Linux to initialize KMS/DRM, but I'm facing some issues with DRM_IOCTL_MODE_GETRESOURCES. This macro is defined as follows in /usr/include/libdrm/drm.h:

```
#define DRM_IOCTL_MODE_GETRESOURCES DRM_IOWR(0xA0, struct drm_mode_card_res)
```

However, when I try to replace DRM_IOCTL_MODE_GETRESOURCES by "0xa0" or "0xA0", I don't get the same output!

This is my code:

```
#include <libdrm/drm_mode.h>
#include <libdrm/drm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>


int main()
{
  int dri_fd = open("/dev/dri/card0", O_RDWR);
  struct drm_mode_card_res res;
  ioctl(dri_fd, DRM_IOCTL_SET_MASTER, 0);

  // This is the problematic one:
  ioctl(dri_fd, DRM_IOCTL_MODE_GETRESOURCES, &res);

  printf("VALUE: %d", res.count_connectors);
  return(0);
}
```

This outputs:  VALUE= 4

If I change "DRM_IOCTL_MODE_GETRESOURCES" by "0xa0" or "0xA0", it outputs: VALUE = 0, which is very strange to me.

(You may ask why I'm not using the defined macro, the thing is I'm trying to write this code in x86_64 assembly, so I need the arguments for the syscall! :(  )

I'm using g++  but I've tried the same syscall with assembly (nasm) and I got the same result (value = 0)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You do realise that you need to expand `DRM_IOCTL_MODE_GETRESOURCES` 4 levels deep to before you do the replacement: `DRM_IOCTL_MODE_GETRESOURCES` -> `DRM_IOWR` -> `_IOWR` -> `_IOC` all macros with bit twiddling going on at the bottom level.

Comment: oh I see! thanks a lot, its working now!! :)